# AtrributeError: Dict has no object class_name

Tags: python, nlp, ibm-cloud, classification, ibm-watson

Im trying to parse a website, tokenize it and store different sentences in an array, so this becomes an array of strings. I need to access the classes returned from the json. For example, i have to classes: nhate and hate. If the class is hate and the confidence for that class is > 0.50, then do something. However i cannot access the classes.

```
words = text.split(".")
c=0
for i in words:

  if not words[c]:
      words[c] = "this was empty before." 
  classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('90e7b4x199-nlc-36073',words[c])
  result = json.dumps(classes, indent=2)
  if (classes.class_name == 'hate' and classes.confidence > 0.50):
    print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2)) 
  c=c+1
```

The error that im getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                        
File "parse.py", line 45, in <module>                        
if (classes.class_name == 'hate' and classes.confidence > 0.50) 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'class_name'
```

**Edited**: The json that im getting is like this:

```
{
  "classifier_id": "10D41B-nlc-1",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier    /api/v1/classifiers/10D41B-nlc-1/classify?text=How%20hot%20wil/10D41B-nlc-1",
  "text": "How hot will it be today?",
  "top_class": "nhate",
  "classes": [
    {
      "class_name": "nhate",
      "confidence": 0.9998201258549781
    },
    {
      "class_name": "hate",
      "confidence": 0.00017987414502176904
    }
  ]
}
```

*Edited*

print(classes) gives me:

```
    {u'url': u'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1
    /classifiers/90e7b4x199-nlc-36073', 
    u'text': u' A Partnership With Abu Shaklak Printing House', 
    u'classes': 
    [{u'class_name': u'nhate.', u'confidence': 0.9398546
    187612434}, {u'class_name': u'hate.', u'confidence':   0.0449277873541271}, {u'cla
    ss_name': u'Feels good man', u'confidence': 0.015217593884629425}],     u'classifier
    _id': u'90e7b4x199-nlc-36073', u'top_class': u'nhate.'}
```

Comment: That means the dict classes is not having any key called class_name. Try to print(classes) and see the exact name

Comment: Since the error says that it is `dict` object; you should try to access it like `classes[class_name]`

Comment: @Exprator there is a clearly a key with name "class_name" in the json.

Comment: ok then use dict['key_name']

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri i tried :"if classes[class_name] == hate" but im getting the same error that class_name is not defined

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I just edited the question to add the json object that im getting.

Comment: Should be `if classes[0][class_name] == hate`.

Comment: @stovfl can you explain what is classes[0] ?

Comment: @stovfl `class_name` should be in quotes?

Comment: ` classes` is a list of `dict` . @Chris Snow: You are right, " quotes". But rereading it, possible `if classes[1].class_name == hate` or ` for class in classes` .

Comment: @stovfl i tried using `if (classes[1].class_name == "nhate")` and I'm getting  KeyError: 1

Comment: May I see, `print ( classes)`.

Comment: @stovfl i just edited the question, can you check it?

Comment: May I see `print( classes['classes'])`. Seems we are misleaded, your var name `classes` != dict[' classes'] .

Comment: @stovfl  print( classes['classes']) gives the following result: `[{u'class_name': u'nhate.', u'confidence': 0.9525668254559034}, {u'class_name':
u'hate.', u'confidence': 0.0389566476309232}, {u'class_name': u'Feels good man' `
 u'confidence': 0.008476526913173313}]

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do something like this:

```
import json

# For demonstration purposes, use the data from the question rather than calling the api:

# data = natural_language_classifier.classify('90e7b4x199-nlc-36073',words[c])

data = json.loads("""{
  "classifier_id": "10D41B-nlc-1",
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier    /api/v1/classifiers/10D41B-nlc-1/classify?text=How%20hot%20wil/10D41B-nlc-1",
  "text": "How hot will it be today?",
  "top_class": "nhate",
  "classes": [
    {
      "class_name": "nhate",
      "confidence": 0.9998201258549781
    },
    {
      "class_name": "hate",
      "confidence": 0.00017987414502176904
    }
  ]
}""")

def hate_gt(data, confidence):
  if 'classes' in data:
    for cls in data['classes']:
      if cls['class_name'] == 'hate' and cls['confidence'] > confidence:
          return True
  return False

print(hate_gt(data, 0.00001))  # True
print(hate_gt(data, 0.5))      # False
```

Try it here: https://repl.it/Hl9b/1

I'm not sure what this API contract looks like, so I didn't want to make any assumptions that 'hate' will always be the second item in the array.

Notice as well that I changed the `classes` variable name to `data` as `classes['classes']` is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
json_result = natural_language_classifier.classify('90e7b4x199-nlc-36073',words[c])
classes =  json_result['classes']
if (classes[1]['class_name'] == "hate" ...
```